# What do $d_{i}$ and $d_{o}$ represent in this diagram from Pearson Physics 2009?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

I'm having trouble understanding this diagram from *Pearson Physics* *2009*:

[image]

For the most part, within the context (page 661 of the text), there is not really any kind of legend or labels. I'm confused with all of it, but mainly I want to know what $d_{i}$ and $d_{o}$  represent. I suppose I can make a reasonable guess that $d_{o}$ represents the distance to the object from the concave surface, but as for $d_{i}$ I'm completely lost.

Comment: did you read what is on page 661? all the text on that page aids to explain this image. it reads: "$h_o$ is the height of the object,
$h_i$ is the height of the image,
$d_o$ is the distance between the mirror vertex and the object, and
$d_i$ is the distance between the mirror vertex and the image."

goes on to show how to arrive at the mirror equation using those variables and focal length.

Comment: I could have freaking swore...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $d_o$ is the distance of the object ($O$) from the mirror surface.
And likewise, $d_i$ is the distance of the image ($I$) from the mirror surface.

Here the image ($I$) is a real image (i.e. the rays actually meet there).
For a [concave mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curved_mirror#Concave_mirrors) the image is a real image in front of the mirror,
if the distance $d_o$ of the original object is larger than $f$ (the focal length).

Comment: Can you go into more detail? Isn't the image supposed to be behind the mirror surface?